# I have sql data 17949366 in mysql workbench, I try to write query for finding duplicate data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT id, survey_id
From Table1
Where survey_id IN(
  select survey_id
  from Table1
  Group By survey_id
  having count(id)>1
)
```

THIS IS MY QUERY BUT I HAVE BIG DATA I GUESS STILL FETCHING IN IT IN MYSQL WORKBENCH. ANY IDEA I CAN MAKE THIS PROCESS FASTER ?

Comment: Please don't shout, and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: Writing in all capital is considered as shouting. I suggest to correct it. Also can you explain what this query is written for?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I assume you mean you have 17,949,366 rows in your table, in MySQL, not in Workbench as thats just a program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes `EXISTS` performs better because it returns as soon as it finds the row:

```
SELECT t.id, t.survey_id
From Table1 AS t
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM Table1
  WHERE id <> t.id AND survey_id = t.survey_id
)
```

I assume `id` is the primary key in the table.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see query execution plan. The query pattern here calls for a suitable index available.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(*),column from table group by column having count(column) > 1
```

You can simply group by directly. No need for sub query.
Try to add index for column

Comment: The OP doesn't seem interested in returning the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your data without subqueries:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(survey_id) as survey_ids
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(survey_id)>1;
```

Comment: thank you running your query, fetching now, quick more question how to write query remove the duplicate ride the way? My query was selecting duplicate do know how i can do remove the duplicate ?

Comment: Hi Denis i got different result with your query than mine :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan.

On large sets, we will get better performance when an index can be used to satisfy a GROUP BY, rather than a "Using filesort" operation.

Personally, I'd avoid the `IN (subquery)` and instead use a join to a derived table. I don't know that this has any impact on performance, or in which versions of MySQL there might be a difference. Just my personal preference to write the query this way:

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.survey_id
    FROM ( -- inline view
           SELECT s.survey_id
             FROM Table1 s
            GROUP BY s.survey_id
           HAVING COUNT(s.id) > 1
         ) r
    JOIN Table1 t
      ON t.survey_id = r.survey_id
```

We do want an index that has `survey_id` as the leading column. That allows the `GROUP BY` to be satisfied from the index, avoiding a potentially expensive "Using filesort" operation. That same index will also be used for the join to the original table.

```
   CREATE INDEX Table1_IX2 ON Table1 (survey_id, id, ...)
```

NOTE: If this is InnoDB and if `id` is the cluster key, then including the `id` column doesn't use any extra space (it does enforce some additional ordering), but more importantly it makes the index a *covering index* for the outer query (query can be satisfied entirely from the index, without lookups of pages in the underlying table.)

With that index defined, we'd expect the `EXPLAIN` output Extra column show "Using index" for the outer query, and to omit "Using filesort" for the derived table (inline view).

---

Again, use `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan.

Comment: And you would choose those methods over a simple join (and DISTINCT)?

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes. I would choose to use EXPLAIN to see the execution plan. I would choose a query pattern that makes use of a suitable index. I would choose a query pattern that avoids an expensive "Using filesort" operation. I would also choose this query pattern for the more general case, beyond just "at least one other row", e.g. `COUNT(s.id) > 4`. For the special case of `>1`, I'd opt for the EXISTS subquery pattern (demonstrated by forpas) when we have a guarantee that `id` is PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY, with a suitable index available. The query pattern here doesn't require id PRIMARY KEY